# How to Let Two Processes Running on Different Hosts Communicate via Named Pipe

Tags: c#, .net, named-pipes

I'm using named pipes to let two processes running on different hosts communicate.
Here is the server code:

```
public class PipeServer
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        PipeSecurity ps = new PipeSecurity();
        ps.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule("Everyone",
            PipeAccessRights.FullControl,
            System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));

        NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(
           "testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 4,
           PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.WriteThrough,
           1024, 1024, ps);

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeServer);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeServer);

        do {
            try {
                pipeServer.WaitForConnection();
                sw.WriteLine("Waiting");
                sw.Flush();
                pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();
                string message = sr.ReadLine();
                sw.WriteLine("got message " + message);
            } catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; } finally {
                pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();
                if (pipeServer.IsConnected) { pipeServer.Disconnect(); }
            }
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

... and here is the client code:

```
public class PipeClient
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(
            "10.225.154.59", "testpipe",
            PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.None,
            TokenImpersonationLevel.None);

        if (pipeClient.IsConnected != true) { pipeClient.Connect(); }

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeClient);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeClient);

        string temp;
        temp = sr.ReadLine();

        if (temp == "Waiting") {
            try {
                sw.WriteLine("Hello");
                sw.Flush();
                pipeClient.Close();
            } catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
        }
    }
}
```

After I start `PipeServer` on a remote host, I run the client on my workstation... but I always get the following error message:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream.Connect(Int32 timeout)
at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream.Connect()
PipeClient.Program.Main(String[] args) in G:\My Projects\Lab\NamePipes\Program.cs:line 18
```

The user that runs `PipeServer` on the remote host is different than the user that runs `PipeClient` on my workstation... but this should not be an issue since I've added the proper access rule.

Am I missing something?

**Edit**
Some additional info as suggested by Alexei. The user that runs the server is a local administrator, while the user that runs client is a domain user. Is there a way to let anybody send a message to the server?

Comment: You are missing information on whether users are domain accounts or local accounts and whether client's account actually can access server's machine.

Comment: man, you're reinventing the wheel. trust me, use WCF

Comment: Just updated my post with more info.